# Is there a way to view how many tabs I have opened today in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

Does an extension or something exist, that lets me see how many tabs I open in Chrome over the span of a day, hour, week, whatever?

There used do be some kind of built in stats using about:stats, but that does not work any more.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. But this will start counting only after you install thins Extension.

This will say the number of tabs that are open.
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cacjfndbmpdblhkmamkhmdadnoddgoon?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon

If you want to know the number of tabs you have opened over a period of time then you may need to install,

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/enicioldoboigjfokpmjoeikioildoke?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon